# variable referencing in getter method

Tags: java, getter-setter

Is the following declaration in getter method legal?

**App.java**

```
package com.abc.xyz.db.main;

    public class App 
    {
        public static String zipfilename;
    ........................
    }
```

**PatchFileDetailsForIndividualFilesInPatch.java**

```
import com.abc.xyz.db.main.App;

public class PatchFileDetailsForIndividualFilesInPatch {

    private String patchFileName;

    public String getPatchFileName() {
        return patchFileName;
    }

    public void setPatchFileName(String patchFileName) {
        this.patchFileName = App.zipfilename;
    }
.....................
}
```

Even though IDE is not complaining, yet I am feeling confused whether is this the correct way of passing variables declared in one class to a getter method in another class.

I am new to Java. I know this is an extremely rudimentary question but your guidance would help me :)

Regards

Comment: So,... your setter method has a parameter that it is simply ignoring?

Comment: It is legal... otherwise it would not compile. But normal usage of setter is `this.patchFileName = patchFileName;`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I know a setter method is being wasted, but I don't know how to pass a variable to a setter method..

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek will it be able to fetch the value stored in zipfilename variable?

Comment: It should not be fetched.... it's a setter it should set variable, not fetch value. If you want to make `patchFileName` have value of  `zipFileName`, you should call setter with the value.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek like this patchLogDTO.setPatchFileName(App.zipfilename); ?

Comment: Yes. Like that.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek got it